# Why Genymotion is lagging?

Tags: android, lag, genymotion

I have lag when I run a device with Android 9 or above. What's the problem?
My Config: CPU: Core i3-11300H/ GPU:GTX 1650 NoteBook

I updated to latest version, I restarted my Laptop, I changed settings, and everything is OK just lagging

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Genymotion is using the Intel iGPU instead of the discrete GTX GPU. You need to force Genymotion to use the Nvidia GTX, see https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020501537